# Get logcat to display the entire downloaded HTML

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

> I want my logcat to show entire fetched HTML code not just some part of 
>    it as i'm using regex to dynamically find certain resources.
>   I have tried to print the fetched HTML into a text file(on PC not on the 
>    android device) but nothing seem to work.

The text file is just for rough work while working with the HTML so that can get the regular expression.

```
private void writeToFile(String data)
    {
        try
        {
            OutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream("getNames.txt");
            Writer outputStreamWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("EXCEPTION",e.toString());
        }
    }
```

can you guys please show how to do file handling properly in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

below should work, for printing log use any mode you would like use, I have shown all in catch block.:

```
private void writeToFile(String data)
    {
       try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("getNames.txt");
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer)) {

            bw.write(data);

        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("EXCEPTION",e.getMessage()); //print in info mode
            Log.d("EXCEPTION",e.getMessage()); //print in debug
            Log.e("EXCEPTION",e.getMessage()); //print error
        }
    }
```

OR create file object where you have permission to write or give permission to writable.change path name of your system.

```
private void writeToFile(String data)
        {
       File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\test\\getNames.txt");
        file.setWritable(true);
           try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("getNames.txt");
                 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer)) {

                bw.write(data);

            } 
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.i("EXCEPTION",e.getMessage()); //print in info mode
                Log.d("EXCEPTION",e.getMessage()); //print in debug
                Log.e("EXCEPTION",e.getMessage()); //print error
            }
        }
```

Comment: `I/EXCEPTION: getNames.txt (Read-only file system)` , im getting this error again. what to do next ?

Comment: make sure you have permission to write.

Comment: do you mean in windows or somehow from within android studio itself?

Comment: you have to give permission to your work space project folder to write, if not working then see my other solution where you can give file path.I have updated my answer.

Comment: ` I/EXCEPTION: getNames.txt (Read-only file system)` along with **result of file.setWritable is ignored** what to do now?